# http status 404 hello.jsp (apache tomcat 6)

Tags: spring, apache, jsp, tomcat, ant

im new to using apache and spring framework and i've been using this tutorial for learning: http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html
i made an .jsp file however my browser tells me "The requested resource is not available."

the .jsp file is pretty simple

```
<html>
  <head><title>Hello :: Spring Application</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello - Spring Application</h1>
    <p>Greetings.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

entering http://localhost:8080/project/hello.htm gives me a 404.
my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>project</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>project</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>       

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you are following a guide that has been written 7 years ago. It even uses Ant. Are you aware of the new Spring docs: https://spring.io/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 error means the requested resource is not in the server.
Your problem can be either

1. Not properly matching hello.htm to any controller

bean id="/hello.htm" class="foo.controller" or

2. You have to put your hello.jsp in webcontent folder, along with index.jsp. Not in WEB-INF folder. Refer tutorial.